# AWS EC2 Security Group Custom TCP Rule for HTTP NGINX not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I have two instances which runs Kubernetes cluster inside of it. I have deployed NGINX microservice and exposed it with NodePort, and port 30757 got allocated for that service.

When I add rule in security group as "Allow all traffic from anywhere" I can access the NGINX with http://Node_Pubic_IP:30757. But when I change the rule to "Custom TCP Rule for 30757 port from anywhere" I couldn't access NGINX.

What is going on here?

Comment: that is really bizarre. Enable VPC flow logs for the subnet and see what it says.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to telnet on this port. And where are you  applying this security group , on kubernetes node instance or on master instance?

Comment: applying security group for all the instances... nginx pod is deployed into node instance..